# Wcsstr no case sensitivity

Tags: c, windows, driver, case-insensitive

Does anybody know how to use `wcsstr` with no case sensitivity on C? If this important I will use it in kernel driver.

Comment: What part of the kernel should take response on this library function call?

Comment: There are [some](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/c/code/216564) [examples](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/string/article.php/c5641) if you search properly. While I didn't find any using `whcar_t`, it shouldn't be hard to modify them to support it.

Answer (score 7):

If you're programming under Windows you can use the [`StrStrI()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-strstriw) function.

You can't use it in a kernel driver so you have to [write it by your own](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/uk/vclanguage/thread/1f0d59a0-97f0-44f0-b390-60b13f73f255). In that example `toupper()` is used and should be replace with `RtlUpcaseUnicodeChar` (as pointed out by Rup). To summarize you need something like this:

```
char *stristr(const wchar_t *String, const wchar_t *Pattern)
{
      wchar_t *pptr, *sptr, *start;

      for (start = (wchar_t *)String; *start != NUL; ++start)
      {
            while (((*start!=NUL) && (RtlUpcaseUnicodeChar(*start) 
                    != RtlUpcaseUnicodeChar(*Pattern))))
            {
                ++start;
            }

            if (NUL == *start)
                  return NULL;

            pptr = (wchar_t *)Pattern;
            sptr = (wchar_t *)start;

            while (RtlUpcaseUnicodeChar(*sptr) == RtlUpcaseUnicodeChar(*pptr))
            {
                  sptr++;
                  pptr++;

                  if (NUL == *pptr)
                        return (start);
            }
      }

      return NULL;
}
```

Comment: [`StrStrI`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773439.aspx) is in shlwapi which won't be available to a kernel driver. But yes, code-your-own is probably the way to do although I suspect `toupper` won't be available here either.

Comment: Actually I take that back - there's [`RtlUpcaseUnicodeChar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff563003.aspx)

Comment: The answer links to `StrStrIA`, but wouldn't [StrStrIW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-strstriw) be the appropriate alternative for `wcsstr`? (takes `PCWSTR` or [const wchar_t*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/working-with-strings) inputs)

Comment: @djvg absolutely, thank you!